# Local PHP Web App, how to protect the database password

Tags: php, database, passwords

I am trying to secure a PHP web application which runs out of a WAMP-style local installation.

Currently, passwords for the app's database are just in the .php files. I thought about encrypting them, but any person can just step through the code to decrypt them pretty easily.

This does not run on a web server, it runs on the user's PC. Has anyone here attempted to secure this type of application, and perhaps shipped a compiled program to return the passwords, or perhaps used an external keystore somehow?

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Clarification: The database is also on the local PC.

Comment: Is your database remote, in terms of an arbitrary client using your web app?

Comment: There are a LOT of very robust external authentication providers out there. Firebase and OAuth to name a few.

Comment: @RussJ wouldn't I still need to store the token though in the program? Perhaps I can just encrypt the token with something rudimentary.

Comment: This isn’t a silly question: whom are you trying to protect the password from?

Comment: Yes. I mean technically speaking, no system is 100% hack-proof, but Firebase and OAuth provide would-be hackers a tough road to success...

Comment: @Manngo interesting question actually, I haven't thought that through. Since the app is used in a competition organization, I think the biggest risk is a current user finding out the password, then going to a competition and logging into the database over WiFi. I could look at other mechanisms, but the password sitting in the .php file seemed like a red flag.

Comment: @RussJ I would be inclined to accept your answer in my case, I could store the encrypted token in an external file rather than in the .php, then hard-code the provider to look to that file so that PHP is out of it. It would not be 1000% foolproof, but to your point it would make the effort significant.

Comment: Someone once told me that cyber-security is like being chased by a starving, angry black bear. You cannot stop the bear, but you can set bear traps to slow it down. The more traps you set, the better.

Comment: @RussJ I love it! Unsure if you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept it, if we keep it up the moderators may close the question on us but I needed to ask it and I got a ton of information that I needed!

Comment: done!...........

Comment: You can save the key on any web API and can get the access token instead of key when an application starts using API... instead of storing key on app I prefer to store access token upto some time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a LOT of very robust external authentication providers out there. Firebase and OAuth to name a few. Technically speaking, no system is 100% hack-proof, but Firebase and OAuth provide would-be hackers a tough road to success

Comment: the problem will come when you want to invalidate the token on logout or password change...

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use ENV variable in that case make .env file and store password in that and call the same in application.
2. You can create environment variable in Apache config file and call from there in your application this is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to protect a database connection credentials if you are giving the client / user the source code. Basically if your app can access it and the source code is there for them to use, read, parse then they have the same access as the software does.